# Firestore/Javascript: How to get a data from map field of a sub-document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a specific data from a map of my sub-document in firestore and display it my web application page. I don't really know how to call the data during the `var.textContent = doc.data().` part...

Note: stages is a field map

Image to help with my question:

[image]

So far this is what I have:

```
<script>
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
 if(user){
  this.userId = user.uid;
 } //stores the user id in variable

const fitbitremSleep= document.querySelector('#fitbitSleepListRemSleep');

function renderFitbitSleep(doc){

 let li = document.createElement('li');
 li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);

 let remSleep = document.createElement('span');
 let lbremSleep = document.createElement('span');

 remSleep.textContent = doc.data();
 lbremSleep.textContent = "Minutes of REMSleep:  ";  

 li.appendChild(lbremSleep);
 li.appendChild(remSleep);

 fitbitremSleep.appendChild(li);
 }

 let userRef1 = 
 firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("fitbit_sleep").orderBy("dateAdded", 
 "desc").limit(1);
 return userRef1.get()
 .then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
   console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
   renderFitbitSleep(doc);
   });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
   console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
   });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

To clarify my question even more is it possible to get a content of field map in firestore using `doc.data()`? Because I've been using `doc.data()` to get fields of a sub-document.

**EXAMPLE**

> Because I've been using `doc.data()` to get fields of a sub-document.

**My code to set a non-map field:**

```
minutesAsleep.textContent = doc.data().minutesAsleep;
```

note that: `minutesAsleep` is non-map field within the sub-document already and can be easily pulled out from the database using the aforementioned code.

Field `minutesAsleep` in the database:
[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT OF THE EXAMPLE:**
[image]

Comment: It would help a lot if you produce a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @aviya.developer edited with new example and images to explain that non map fields can be easily pulled out of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimenting and tinkering with the code:

```
 remSleep.textContent = doc.data();
 lbremSleep.textContent = "Minutes of REMSleep:  ";
```

Replace with this:

```
 remSleep.textContent = doc.data().stages.remSleep;
 lbremSleep.textContent = "Minutes of REMSleep:  ";
```

**to explain further:**

```
doc.data().
```

gets the docs data

**then,**

```
doc.data().stages
```

gets the docs data under map field stages

**finally,**

```
doc.data().stages.remSleep;
```

gets the docs data under map field stages and gets the data of remSleep under that map.

I hope this could help anyone especially those who are developing using javascript and firebase :)